# How to search for examples of design patent applications?

Tags: patent-applications, design-patent

I want to learn by looking at some examples of design patent applications.

Is there a public repository of the history of a design patent application process as there are for trademarks?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - Like all types of patents, all of the back-and-forth between the applicant and the USPTO are available to the public. They can be found in [Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). You will need to enter either the application number or the patent number. The site is fussy about the format of the number.  For the patent number of design patents use the "D" (but not the "US") and be sure to set the radio button to "Patent Number". The tab "Image File Wrapper" has a chronological record of all paper sent between the applicant and office. You will notice that the format required for a design patent application doesn't much look like the format of an issued design patent.